# Error en C# Visual Studio en Netcore

Tags: c#, visual-studio

muy buenos tardes.
Tengo el siguiente error en la realizacion de un proyecto

El proyecto "..\CapaPresentacion\CapaPresentacion.csproj" tiene "netcoreapp3.1" como destino. No puede hacer referencia a este un proyecto con ".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" como destino.

Es un proyecto en C# que esta divido en capas, si alguien me puede acesorar para solucionar este problema, seria de muchísima ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Para hacer un proyecto compatible con .NET Framework y .NET Core, el target o destino tiene que ser .NET Standard.

Sin embargo esta compatibilidad llegó hasta .NET Standard / .NET Core 2.0 como se muestra en la [documentación oficial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard#net-implementation-support).

En conclusión, no es posible hacer referencia a un proyecto .NET Core 3.1 desde ninguna versión de .NET Framework.